# Logic for an FPGA to output an analog clock on a VGA screen

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vga

I am implementing an analog clock which will display an hour and minute hand on a vga screen 640x480 with clock centered at 480x480. The clock will update once a minute. The timing diagram below shows the timing for HSYNC and VSYNC and their position relative to a 26.25MHz clock.

This is my first course in VHDL, **I want to know what I am missing in clock.vhd and how to write the test bench effectively so I can get the output**

[image: Timing Diagram]

I have a separate component called counter.vhd which gets instantiated twice in clock.vhd, one as the horizontal counter and one as the vertical counter.

Here is my code for counter.vhd, clock.vhd and my testbench which is not complete.

counter.vhd

```
entity counter is
Port ( clk : STD_LOGIC;
       reset : STD_LOGIC;
                      ena : STD_LOGIC;
                      rollover_out : STD_LOGIC;
                      address : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                      sync : STD_LOGIC
                     );

-- Generics
generic (count_value :=800;
                    sync_start :=10;
                    sync_end :=20
                    );
end counter;

architecture Behavioral of counter is

signal temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0); -- counts to 800

process (clk, reset)
    if (reset = 0) then
    temp <="000000";
    sync <='1';
    rollover_out <='0';
    else (clk'event & clk = 1);
    rollover_out <='0';
    temp <= temp+"000000";
            if (temp = count_value - 1) then
            temp <="000000"
            rollover_out <= '1';
            end if;
            if (sync_start = temp) then
            sync <= '0';
            end if;
            if (sync_end = temp) then 
            sync <= '1';
            end if;
    end if;
end process;

address <= temp (8 downto 1);

begin
    -- 800 horizontal sync counter
    process(h_count_reg,h_end,pixel_tick)
            begin
                    if (pixel_tick = '1') then -- 25MHz tick
                            if (h_end='1') then 
                                    h_count_next <= (others => '0');
                            else
                                    h_count_next <= h_count_reg+1;
                            end if;
                    else
                            h_count_next <= h_count_reg;
                    end if;
    end process;

    -- 525 vertical sync counter 
    process(v_count_reg,h_end,v_end,pixel_tick)
            begin
                    if (pixel_tick = '1') and (h_end = '1') then
                            if (v_end = '1') then 
                                    v_count_next <= (others => '0');
                            else 
                                    v_count_next <= v_count_reg+1;
                            end if;
                    else
                            v_count_next <= v_count_reg;
                    end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

clock.vhd

```
entity clock is
Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
       hsync : out  STD_LOGIC;
       vsync : out  STD_LOGIC;
       video_on : out  STD_LOGIC;
                      p_tick : out STD_LOGIC;
       pixel_x : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
       pixel_y : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0)
                      );
 end clock;

 architecture Behavioral of clock is
 -- VGA 640x480 sync parameters
 constant HD: integer:=640; -- horizontal display area
 constant HF: integer:=16; -- horizontal front porch
 constant HB: integer:=48; -- horizontal back porch
 constant HR: integer:=96; -- horizontal retrace "sync pulse"
 constant VD: integer:=480; -- vertical display area
 constant VF: integer:=10; -- vertical front porch
 constant VB: integer:=33; -- vertical back porch
 constant VR: integer:=2; -- vertical retrace "sync pulse"

-- mod2 counter to generate a 25MHz enable tick
signal mod2_reg : std_logic; 
signal mod2_next : std_logic;

-- sync counters for the horizontal and vertical scans
signal v_count_reg : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal v_count_next : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal h_count_reg : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal h_count_next : unsigned(9 downto 0);

-- output buffer
signal v_sync_reg : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal h_sync_reg : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal v_sync_next : unsigned(9 downto 0); 
signal h_sync_next : unsigned(9 downto 0);

-- status signal
signal h_end : std_logic;
signal v_end : std_logic;
signal pixel_tick : std_logic;

component counter
generic (count_value :=800;
                    sync_start :=10;
                    sync_end :=20
                    );
Port                 (clk : STD_LOGIC;
     reset : STD_LOGIC;
                    ena : STD_LOGIC;
                    rollover_out : std_logic;
     sync : STD_LOGIC;
                    address : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
                    );

signal carry : std_logic;                        
end component;

horizontal: counter 
generic map (count_value :=800;
                            sync_start :=10;
                            sync_end :=20
                            );                                        
PORT MAP (clk <= clk;
                    reset <= reset;
                    ena <= '1';
                    rollover_out <= carry;
                    sync <= hsync
                    address <= open
                    );

vertical: counter
generic map (count_value :=525;
                            sync_start := 2;
                            sync_end := 4
                            );
Port map (clk <= clk;
                    reset <= reset;
                    ena <= carry;
                    rollover_out <= open;
                    sync <= vsync;        
                    address <= open
                    );                        

begin 
    -- register
    process(clk,reset)
            begin
                    if (reset='1') then
                            mod2_reg <= '0';
                            v_count_reg <=(others=>'0');
                            h_count_reg <=(others=>'0');
                            v_sync_reg <=(others=>'0');
                            h_sync_reg <=(others=>'0');
                    elsif(clk' event and clk='1') then
                            mod2_reg <= mod2_next;
                            v_count_reg <= v_count_next;
                            h_count_reg <= h_count_next;
                            v_sync_reg <= v_sync_next;
                            h_sync_reg <= h_sync_next;
                    end if;
    end process;

    -- mod2 circuit to generate 25MHz enable tick
    mod2_next <= not mod2_reg;

    -- 25MHz pixel tick
    pixel_tick <= '1' when mod2_reg = '1' else '0';

    -- status
    h_end <= -- end of horizontal counter
            '1' when h_count_reg = (HD+HF+HB+HR-1) else --799
            '0';
    v_end <= -- end of vertical counter
            '1' when v_count_reg = (VD+VF+VB+VR-1) else --524
            '0';

    -- video on/off
    video_on <= '1' when (h_count_reg < HD) and (v_count_reg < VD) else '0';

    -- output signals
    hsync <= h_sync_reg;
    vsync <= v_sync_reg;        
    pixel_x <= std_logic_vector(h_count_reg);
    pixel_y <= std_logic_vector(v_count_reg);
    p_tick <= pixel_tick;

end Behavioral;
```

testbench

```
ENTITY clock_tb IS
END clock_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF clock_tb IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT clock
PORT(
     clk : IN  std_logic;
     reset : IN  std_logic;
     hsync : OUT  std_logic;
     vsync : OUT  std_logic;
     video_on : OUT  std_logic;
     p_tick : OUT  std_logic;
     pixel_x : OUT  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
     pixel_y : OUT  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;


--Inputs
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal reset : std_logic := '0';

     --Outputs
signal hsync : std_logic;
signal vsync : std_logic;
signal video_on : std_logic;
signal p_tick : std_logic;
signal pixel_x : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal pixel_y : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);

-- Clock period definitions
constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
uut: clock PORT MAP (
      clk => tb_clk,
      reset => tb_reset,
      hsync => tb_hsync,
      vsync => tb_vsync,
      video_on => tb_video_on,
      p_tick => tb_p_tick,
      pixel_x => tb_pixel_x,
      pixel_y => tb_pixel_y
    );

-- Clock process definitions
clk_process :process
begin
            clk <= '0';
            wait for clk_period/2;
            clk <= '1';
            wait for clk_period/2;
end process;


-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin                
  -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
            wait for 100 ns;        

  wait for clk_period*10;

  -- insert stimulus here 

  wait;
end process;

END;
```

Comment: What is the question?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And why do you want to centre it on the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @BrianDrummond no particular reason, it is just the design constraint.

Comment: Not to belabor Ian's point, but what is your question?

Comment: @user1155120 I want to know what else to implement in clock.vhd and my testbench

Comment: Okay then.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @user1155120 How do I apply the timing constraints from the table of hsync and vsync into my testbench? Do i need to place those constraints in clock.vhd as well?

Comment: And what are you testing, sync timing?

Comment: @user1155120 I dont think i am testing the sync timing, rather using those contraints to look up hsync and vsync which in turn displays the minute and hour hand of my clock that I output

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to segment your task up into two sections.

First you need a design that when given the 26.25MHz clock will generate the HSYNC, VSYNC and video data signals to be put out on the pins of the FPGA.

Second you need to fill in that video data with an RGB / YCbCr bitmap of pixel data that represent a graphic for the clock hands. This block would take in the video timing signals and the clock and then fill the video data in.

How you generate the clock hands is the tricky part and I suspect where the person running the course is looking for some ingenuity to solve that particular problem.

Start small and build up. Try and get the design together to generate the timing signals and put a flat block of colour or black and white on the screen. It is possible to create a testbench that will then save that pixel data to a file which can be processed into a bitmap, so that you can see what the result would be in simulation before you get to hardware.